# Pandas data analysis: finding frequency of responses

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

My data looks like this:

| question | answer |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 1 |
| Q1 | 1 |
| Q1 | 1 |
| Q1 | 2 |
| Q1 | 1 |
| Q1 | 3 |
| Q2 | 3 |
| Q2 | 2 |
| Q2 | 4 |
| Q2 | 1 |
| Q2 | 4 |
| Q2 | 1 |
| Q3 | 4 |
| Q3 | 2 |
| Q3 | 4 |
| Q3 | 3 |
| Q3 | 2 |
| Q3 | 5 |

Every question is repeated six times and `answer` can only take values between 1-5. Here is the data in a csv format:

```
question,answer
Q1,1
Q1,1
Q1,1
Q1,2
Q1,1
Q1,3
Q2,3
Q2,2
Q2,4
Q2,1
Q2,4
Q2,1
Q3,4
Q3,2
Q3,4
Q3,3
Q3,2
Q3,5
```

What I'm trying to do is find the number of answers (1-5) given to each question and output this information to arrays. For example, the result for the data above should be:

```
[4, 1, 1, 0, 0] # which means for question 1, answer 1 was chosen 4 times, answer 2 was chosen 1 time, answer 3 was chosen 1 time, answers 4 and 5 were chosen 0 times. 
[2, 1, 1, 2, 0] # for question 2, answer 1 was chosen 2 times, answer 2 was chosen 1 time, answer 3 was chosen 1 time, answer 4 was chosen 2 times and answer 5 was chosen 0 times. 
[0, 2, 1, 2, 1] # etc
# the sum of the elements of each array should equal 6
```

I looked into `pd.value_counts` but I have no idea how to actually use it here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Here is how you would use value_counts `counts = df["answer"].value_counts()`

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab(df['question'], df['answer']).to_numpy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `crosstab` and convert `to_numpy`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['question'], df['answer']).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 1]])
```

There is however a pitfall in case an answer was never chosen in any of the questions. To ensure having all columns you must `reindex`:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['question'], df['answer'])
   .reindex(range(1,5+1), axis=1, fill_value=0)
   .to_numpy()
)
```